# Breeze: Date Formatting

Tags: momentjs, breeze

I'm receiving dates from the server in this format: `Thu Apr 25 16:47:10 UTC+0200 2013`.

The type is `Date`.

I want dates to be displayed in the `DD/MM/YYYY` format. So I've used Moment.js and in the initializer function of my entity, called from `registerEntityTypeCtor`, I do:

```
myEntity.CreatedDate = moment.utc(myEntity.CreatedDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Although that code returns the properly formatted date, myEntity.CreatedDate remains the same.
Actually if I inspect in the Visual Studio debugger and I expand the property, it says 'prototype: Invalid Date'.

I have two questions:

1. Am I doing it the right way ? i.e, it it a good thing to do the
   conversion in the registerEntityTypeCtor?
2. Why is it not working :-) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breeze dates are javascript dates.  What you are doing is setting a date property with a string.  Breeze then attempts to parse the string, via javascript's *Date.parse* method, into a date in order to validate it.  If this fails, Breeze just leaves it alone.

In general, if you want to format any date properties, this should **not** be done in the  model, but rather in the view. In other words, wherever you are displaying the dates, that is the best location to convert the dates into strings. If you are using a binding library like ko or angular, both provide mechanisms for doing this, as do most javascript template engines.

Comment: yes, you are right. I wasn't thinking. I'm using AngularJS and it's as simple as doing {{myEntity.CreatedDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}

Answer (score 0):

```
moment("myEntity.CreatedDate", "Do MMM YYYY").format("DD/MM/YYYY")
```

set "Do MMM YYYY" according to the format which you get in myEntity.CreatedDate